# center of a $C^*$ algebra

Tags: operator-theory, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

Suppose the center of $C^*$ algebra $A$ is 0,does this $C^*$ algebra constructed by simple non-unital $C^*$ algebras.To be more precise,$A$ can be only simple or direct sum of simple non-unital $C^*$ algebras,or tensor product of simple non-unital $C^*$ algebras.

Does there exist other $C^*$-algebras whose center is 0?

Answer (score 2):

A $C^*$-algebra with trivial center need not be simple.  Consider $A=C_0(\mathbb R)\otimes \mathcal K=C_0(\mathbb R,\mathcal K)$, where $\mathcal K$ is compact operators on separable Hilbert space.  The center of $A$ is trivial, but it is not simple, nor is it of the forms you have described.

Comment: The center of $C_0(\mathbb R)$ isn't zero.  The center of $C_0(\mathbb R)\otimes\mathcal K$ is.

Comment: I don't understand why the center of $C_0(\Bbb)$ is not 0, but the center of $C_0(\mathbb R)\otimes\mathcal K$ is 0, would you mind explaining it in details?